# How to disable the "Identical lines" message in Android Studio Run window of a Flutter app

Tags: android-studio, output

After clicking several times on a button that prints something in the Run window, I got the following message

```
I/flutter ( 3988): profileEditing = true
I/chatty  ( 3988): uid=10121(com.example.myapp) 1.ui identical 33 lines
I/flutter ( 3988): profileEditing = true
```

What I want to do is to disable the **"identical 33 lines"** message and print instead the full detailled 33 lines.

***If this is possible***, how can i do it.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to disable this,
but a workaround is to add some unique text to each print:

```
counter = 0
println("profileEditing = true |" + counter++)
```

So you will get:

```
"profileEditing = true | 0"

"profileEditing = true | 1"

"profileEditing = true | 2"

"profileEditing = true | 3"
```